# Integrating differential equations

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, differential

This is the question:

$$dB/(x-yB)=dt$$

After trying several times to solve this, this is what I've come up with:

$$B(t)=xB/y + C(\exp[-ty]), where C=\exp(c)$$

I have a feeling I've made a mistake along the way, and would appreciate it if someone could give me a few pointers!

Thank you :)

Comment: It's not clear which of $x, y$ and $A$ are constants and which are variables and if they're variables, whether they depend on $t.$  $B$ is a function of $t$, so one suspects that $A$ is also?  It's not illegal, but the choice of $x$ and $y$ as constants is not typical.

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{1}{ax-yb}\space\text{d}b=\text{d}t\Longleftrightarrow\int t'(b)\space\text{d}b=\int\frac{1}{ax-yb}\space\text{d}b$$

Use:

1. $$\int t'(b)\space\text{d}b=t(b)+\text{C}$$
2. Substitute $u=ax-by$ and $\text{d}y=-y\space\text{d}b$
   $$\int\frac{1}{ax-yb}\space\text{d}b=-\frac{1}{y}\int\frac{1}{u}\space\text{d}u=-\frac{\ln\left|u\right|}{y}+\text{C}=\text{C}-\frac{\ln\left|ax-by\right|}{y}$$

Comment: Sorry, I wrote the question down wrong. Would I use these steps to answer the question correctly?

Comment: @ArizonaLee I edited my answer.

Comment: @ArizonaLee You're welcome, I'm glad that I could help.